# Compare posted password to MySQL stored crypted password

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My SQL Table:

```
|-ID-|-Username-|-EmailAddress-|-ePassword-|-Permissions-|
----------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    Admin |              |           |             |
|  2 |       Foo|<emailaddress>|<cpassword>|  <default 1>|
|    |          |              |           |             |
|    |          |              |           |             |
```

The code below takes `_POST` data from a form and then refers to the database to check if the username is correct, once the username is correct I want to be able to compare `$password` with `ePassword` from my database,

`ePassword` is encrypted by using crypt. An example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) about crypt says that I must do:

```
if (hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($user_input, $hashed_password)) {
    echo "Password verified!";
}
```

to compare the password, so mine would be:

```
if (hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($password, $hashed_password)) { //changed $user_input to password
    echo "Password verified!";
}
```

But how would I go about getting `ePassword` from the data base and comparing it?

```
//User data
$username = strtolower($_POST['username']);
$password = $_POST['password'];

//login check
if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] != "") {
    echo 'You already are using an Account!';
} else if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == "") {

    //connect to database
    $con =  mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

    //check for connection errors
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    };

    //checks for username
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    $userCheck = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($userCheck > 0) {
                                //Password check goes here
    } else {

    };
    $con->close();
};
```

TL;DR: I want to compare `$password` with `ePassword` from my database with crypt, how can I do this?

Comment: I think you need encrypt user password `$_POST['password']` and compare with ePassword from your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // username and password sent from Form
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $password=crypt($password,saltUsedWhileRegisteringUser); // Encrypted Password
    //Assuming ePassword is the crypted password inserted into DB while User Registeration
    $sql="SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$username' and ePassword ='$password'";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);//If count > 1 then valid user else not a valid one.
```

Comment: `ePassword` is encrypted with crypt - crypt doesn't output something the same twice.

Comment: While registering a user, you would have used salt to generate ePassword and inserted into the DB. Now when the user login , the same salt should be used to get the crypted value of input password. Then only you can compare passwords as per your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($userCheck > 0) {
    //Password check goes here
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $username,$emailAddress,$ePassword,$permissions);
    $password = crypt($password,'the same salt used to create ePassword. without it the string will be always random'); 
    if (hash_equals($password,$ePassword) {
        echo 'user logged in';
    else
        echo 'invalid password';
    }
}
```